# How to get time spent on a fragment/activity

Tags: android, datetime, time

I am developing an app for taking test. I want to check how much time the user has spent on that activity/fragment before submitting the test/task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) task that can be scheduled at fixed rate with [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)), runs in `onResume` and stops in `onPause`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "LOG_TAG";
    int mPassedSeconds = 0; // spent time on the test
    private Timer mTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPassedSeconds++;
                Log.d(TAG, "run: " + mPassedSeconds);
            }
        }, 0, ONE_SECOND);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Note: `mPassedSeconds` will lose its value on configuration change, so you've to handle it.